# Why is the username not appearing in the comment I created

Tags: support, comments

I have tried several times to add the user's name in a comment to alert him of the comment, but it disappears everytime I save the comment.

Here's the link: [Datagrid SelectedItems Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16953833/447356)

I tried entering @Brian, @BrianHinchey but the username is removed no matter how I type it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because he is the post author thus will get notified anyway.

Comment: From the linked faq: "The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use `@name` to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, **the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value**.)"

Comment: One more thing, if you want to make the comment more personal you can start it by "Brian, [comment here]".

Comment: Because of a stupid stupid decision by the SE overlords, who have refused to listen to reason.